# How do you initiate mathjs library on your code

Tags: javascript, mathjs

I want to find the inverse of a matrix with javascript; how can i do that??

I already tried downloading the mathjs library but i dont know how to initiate it

Answer (score 0):

The [website](https://mathjs.org/) has a [starting example](https://jsbin.com/devacu/edit), reproduced below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="math.js | basic usage">
  <title>math.js | basic usage</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // basic usage of math.js
    //
    // website:  http://mathjs.org
    // docs:     http://mathjs.org/docs
    // examples: http://mathjs.org/examples
    
    // functions and constants
    print(math.round(math.e, 3));                // 2.718
    print(math.atan2(3, -3) / math.pi);          // 0.75
    print(math.log(10000, 10));                  // 4
    print(math.sqrt(-4));                        // 2i
    print(math.pow([[-1, 2], [3, 1]], 2));       // [[7, 0], [0, 7]]
    print(math.derivative('x^2 + x', 'x'));      // 2 * x + 1
    
    // expressions
    print(math.evaluate('12 / (2.3 + 0.7)'));    // 4
    print(math.evaluate('12.7 cm to inch'));     // 5 inch
    print(math.evaluate('9 / 3 + 2i'));          // 3 + 2i
    print(math.evaluate('det([-1, 2; 3, 1])'));  // -7
    
    // chaining
    var a = math.chain(3)
        .add(4)
        .multiply(2)
        .done();
    print(a); // 14
    
    // helper function to output formatted results.
    function print(value) {
      var precision = 14;
      document.write(math.format(value, precision) + '<br>');
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```